# Is it possible to find non consecutive repeating character using python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Example:

If I'm give a string a = '**abcdbefg**' what regex matching pattern do i use to get 'b' i.e. the repeating character?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'(.)(?=.+\1)', 'abcdbefg')
# result = ['b']
```

1. `(.)` - a character
2. `(?=)` - a lookahead assertion (i.e. followed by)
3. `.+` - at least 1 characters
4. `\1` - match the first group (i.e. the `(.)`)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
a = 'abcdbefg'

import re

result = re.findall(r'(.)(?=.+\1)', a)
print(*result)
```